# Unable to get count of logins for different time spans

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i am facing an issue while implementing a query to calculate login counts for different time spans(3 months, 6 months, 1 year etc)

I have two tables :

Table X

```
MAIN  LASTLOGIN
```

Table Y

```
MAIN  USERID  LASTLOGIN
```

I want to return the number of logins for last 3 months, last 6 months, last 1 year based on the user id.

Result Table

```
USERID  LOGINCOUNT(3MONTHS)  LOGINCOUNT(6MONTHS)  LOGINCOUNT(1YEAR)
```

I am able to successfully implement the following query which gives the login counts only for last 3 months. How to get the other two columns of 6 months and 1 year.

My query is :

```
  select Y.userid, count(x.lastlogin) AS COUNT_3MONTHS
   from 
   X
   inner join 
   Y
   on X.MAIN = Y.MAIN
   where X.LASTLOGIN > current_date - interval '90' day
   group by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select Y.userid, 
       sum(X.LASTLOGIN > current_date - interval 3 month) as COUNT_3MONTHS,
       sum(X.LASTLOGIN > current_date - interval 6 month) as COUNT_6MONTHS,
       sum(X.LASTLOGIN > current_date - interval 1 year) as COUNT_1YEAR
from X inner join
     Y on
     X.MAIN = Y.MAIN
group by userid;
```

Comment: For this i guess the where condition need not be present. Correct?

Comment: Yes there is no need to have where condition